# Listbox.SelectionChange not firing for an item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox populated with 3 items from an SQLCE database using Linq.
For some reason when I select the item located at index 1, it highlights in the listbox but does not fire the selection change. If I select any other item (index 0 or 2) then the selection fires fine.

Any ideas?

I have checked the item in the database and I can't see anything wrong with it.

EDIT: Requested Code

Xaml

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lbxPlans" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="12" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PlanTemplate}" SelectionChanged="lbxPlans_SelectionChanged">

  <DataTemplate x:Key="PlanTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Run No." VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RunNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Week Day:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Margin="6,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Week Number:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding WeekNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" Margin="6,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Desc:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="7" Margin="6,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And

```
    private void GetProgrammes()
    {
        var pro = from p in Globals.Instance.Database.Programme
                  select p;

        lbxPlans.DataContext = null;
        lbxPlans.DataContext = pro;
    }

private void lbxPlans_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

        if (lbxPlans.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selection Changed!");
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: As Requested rather than creating `pro` from database items and assigning it to the Listbox DataContext I created them manually to eliminate database issues and still the problem is present. I then just ran an experiment by creating a `List<string>` with 3 values and assigned that to the listbox. The issue is still there! so is this now an issue with the Listbox itself?

Comment: Please share your code for the list box and the selection changed event.

Comment: Edited with selection change

Comment: Could you show xaml code with `ListBox`?

Comment: damn, u edited it before me :-)

Comment: @Gaz83 you gave us wrong XAML code `<ListBox x:Name="lbxPlans"...`, you must show `<ListBox x:Name="lbxProgrammes"...` code.

Comment: @kmatyaszek yep I just noticed, sorry my bad :-)

Comment: @Gaz83 can you show us constructor body or place where you invoke `GetProgrammes` method ?

Comment: Its on page load event. Just a simple GetProgrammes()

Comment: @Gaz83 could you show me code with `PlanTemplate`?.

Comment: @kmatyaszek Added PlanTemplate

Comment: Do you manually alter lbxPlans.SelectedIndex anywhere else? Such as in Page_Load or Page_PreRender?

Comment: @Gaz83 you must check `pro`, reason for that behaviour could be null in index equal 1.

Comment: @AntP nope not at all. Its interesting because I just added a ContextMenu with one MenuItem. When you click the MenuItem is shows a messagebox of the selectedIndex. Even though the selection change does not fire off the messagebox does say that the item is selected

Comment: @kmatyaszek checked pro and its fine. Result shows 3 objects as it should

Comment: @Gaz83 the best option will be if you will create sample solution with that. Code that you give us looks good, so error is somewhere else.

Comment: Right after lbxPlans.DataContext = pro; see what the selectedIndex is.  and try lbxPlans.ItemsSource = pro;

Comment: @Blam SelectedIndex remains -1. Setting to ItemSource makes no difference

Comment: If you select 0 or 2 and then 1 it - does not fire then?

Comment: @Blam that is correct and as I mentioned above, visually index 1 is selected and by adding a ContectMenu to the listbox and getting that to fire off a messagebox saying what is selected, it does say the correct index for each item.

Comment: Just a reach but manually populate pro with a list string one two three.  I had a weird case where if two items had the same string value it got confused and stopped on the first - fixed it by using a class.

Comment: @Blam ok I created 3 x pro manually and put them in a List. Set the ListBox.Datacontext to the List. Still the same problem :-(

Comment: Did you try a new project with nothing but that List and Event?

Comment: I have just solved the problem and I am an idiot. I have updated the code above as it was not a copy and paste job which is why no one spotted it earlier. See if you can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lbxPlans.SelectedIndex != 1

You did not trace this in the debugger?

Comment: no I completely missed it! When I first put the code up I copied and pasted the wrong part which was for a different listbox but the code should be the same so I just edited it (lbxProgrammes to lbxPlans) rather than copy and paste again. That's why no one on here could see the problem. I had it written in my program like so `lbxplans.SelectedIndex!=1` with not gaps so when I read it the = made me think it was - lol. Such an idiot, had me going for hours.